# $_GET from URL Not Working

Tags: javascript, php, url, web

I'm using $_GET['username'] to try and pull the username from test.html?username=jsmith and it is returning blank when I echo it out. I thought this was simple but I can't get it to work

Comment: show your code and the `.htaccess` you have where you configured `.html` files to be executed by php

Answer (score 3):

You're calling a static html file. To use PHP code you need to name the file `test.php`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not reading the file like a php. change the extension to .php and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your help!